# Python3系で入力値がtsvファイル内にある場合にその要素をカウントして増やしたい

Tags: python3

Python3系で以下の流れを実行したいです。
その中で、最後のinput値を入力した際に今までの入力値が消されて、その値とカウント数字のみで上書きされてしまいます。
コードでアドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
辞書タブの展開場所やif文のロジックがおかしい所あると思いますが、
よろしくお願いします。

【実現したい事】
①tsvファイルのNAMEカラムの中から飲食店名を出力（実行済）
②yesの場合、出力された飲食店名のCOUNTカラムにある数字を＋１（実行済）
③noの場合、inputで飲食店名を入力させる（実行済）
④その入力された物がtsvに存在しない場合は追加する（既存のデータが今回入力されたデータに上書きされ、消えてしまう）

```
import pandas as pd
import random 

file0 = "/Users/apple/Downloads/practice.tsv"
d = pd.read_table(file0, index_col='NAME')

random_res = random.choice(list(d.index))
print(f"Would you like {random_res} ?")

user_res = input("yes or no ?")
if user_res == "yes":
   d.loc[d.index == random_res, "COUNT"] += 1
   d.to_csv(file0, sep="\t")

dic = {}
favor_res = input("Which restaurant do you prefer ?")
if favor_res == "":
   print("Thank you for your answer !")
else:
   favor_res.replace("\t", "_")

if favor_res in dic:
   dic[favor_res] += 1
else:
   dic[favor_res] = 1

try:
   with open(file0, "w") as f:
   for k, v in dic.items():
      f.write(f"{k}\t{v}\n")
except IOError as e:
   print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dic = {}` を使用しているので、せっかく`d`に読み込まれたデータが無視されてしまっています。
下記のような感じでいかがでしょうか。

ポイント
1. 最初の質問が"yes" "no"どちらの場合でも、pandasのto_csvを使用しています。
2. 流れが分かれやすいよう、そのままpandasのDataFrameを使用しています。
3. practive.tsvのパスをカレントディレクトリに変更しています。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import random

file0 = "./practice.tsv"
d = pd.read_table(file0, index_col='NAME', dtype={"COUNT": int})

random_res = random.choice(list(d.index))
print(f"Would you like {random_res} ?")

user_res = input("yes or no ?: ")
if user_res == "yes":
    d.loc[random_res, "COUNT"] += 1
else:
    favor_res = input("Which restaurant do you prefer ?: ")
    if favor_res == "":
        print("Thank you for your answer !")
        exit()
    else:
        favor_res.replace("\t", "_")

    if favor_res in d.index:
        d.loc[favor_res, "COUNT"] += 1
    else:
        d.loc[favor_res] = {"COUNT": 1}

d.to_csv(file0, sep="\t")
```

Comment: なるほど。ifの条件分岐もそのように処理させるのですね！勉強になりました。